# How to calculate FPS residency in Chrome web internals?

Tags: webrtc, frame-rate, chromium-os

Objective :: Wanted to calculate out of Google Hangout session, how long 30 FPS quality is maintained.

Eg :: Out of 5min GoogleHangout session, using "googFrameRateReceived" variable in chrome://webrtc-internals/, need to know how much % of time 30 FPS quality is maintained.

I couldn't get the location of "googFrameRateReceived" variable in source code.

Answer (score 0):

The framerate received can be queried using the getStats() API of WebRTC. See https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/ for the most authoritative sample. The [w3c webrtc spec](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#example) also has a related example, you need to look for a different type of report though.